# Failover planning for Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, failover

I have an azure mobile service that is running on top of SQLAzure DB. The Database is geo-replicated. I am looking to setup a failover for mobile service in case if the primary endpoint goes down. I have looked into traffic manager but it does not support mobile service endpoints also setting up another mobile service that talks to the replicated DB not possible as the replicated copy is read-only.

What are the possibilities of setting up a failover for mobile services endpoints.

Comment: Are you using the legacy Azure Mobile Services or the new 'Mobile App' that is part of the 'App Service'?

Comment: legacy mobile services and App service Node.js is still not ready for production.

Answer (score 3):

There are several mechanisms for hosting mobile APIs on Azure - Azure Mobile Services is tied to a single region, so you can't fail that over.  Azure Mobile Apps is the next generation of Azure Mobile Services and is built on top of Azure App Service Web Apps - it's an extension of the work there.  As a result, you can leverage all the cool features of Azure App Service for your mobile service.  If you haven't taken a look yet, then take a look at migrating your service to Azure App Service Web Apps.

Once there, Traffic Manager is definitely what you want.  You can read about the process of using Traffic Manager with an Azure web app here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/06/02/using-traffic-manager-with-microsoft-azure-web-site.aspx

Comment: I have looked at it but I am using HTML/Node.JS on the AMS and its still not yet mature on the new Mobile Apps.. besides to be honest the migration path is still not very clear.

Comment: I totally agree on the maturity of the NodeJS version of Azure Mobile Apps.  Check out https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-node - we are still in early preview, but the SDK is coming together nicely.

Comment: I'd be wary about staying on the legacy Mobile Services. I would prioritize migration to the Azure Mobile App as soon as possible.